# Reduce Elastic Map Reduce runtime

Tags: emr, elastic-map-reduce, bigdata

I use Elastic Map Reduce to analyze large amount of data (stored on S3). 
What is the most cost efficient way to reduce the runtime of the job other than increasing the size of the instance.

If I create more smaller files on S3 will it reduce the runtime?

If I create fewer but larger files on S3 will it reduce the runtime?